# using system call in Linux kernel file

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, scheduler, system-calls

I am implementing a custom process scheduler in Linux. And I want to use a system call to record my program so that I can debug easily.

The file I write is

source code : `linux-x.x.x/kernel/sched_new_scheduler.c`

In `sched_new_scheduler.c` could I use `syscall(the id of the system call, parameter);` directly? It seems `syscall();` is used with `#include<sys/syscalls.h>` in C program, but the ".h" can not be found in the `kernel/`.

I just want to know how my program executes by recording something, so could I directly write `printk("something");` in `sched_new_scheduler.c` ? Or try a correct way to use system call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System call look like wrapper around other kernel function one of ways how to use syscall inside kernel is find sub function for exact system call. For example:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode); -> filp_open

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct file* file_open(const char* path, int flags, int rights)
{
    struct file* filp = NULL;
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int err = 0;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());
    filp = filp_open(path, flags, rights);
    set_fs(oldfs);

    if(IS_ERR(filp)) {
        err = PTR_ERR(filp);
        return NULL;
    }

    return filp;
}

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count); -> vfs_write

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int file_write(struct file* file, unsigned long long offset, unsigned char* data, unsigned int size)
{
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int ret;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());

    ret = vfs_write(file, data, size, &offset);

    set_fs(oldfs);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion to find the sub function of the certain system calls. And I found it is complicated to use `printk` by implementing the sub function of it inside the kernel.   But I also found that my `linux-x.x.x/kernel/sched_new_scheduler.c` could use `printk` directly just simply adding `#include<linux/kernel.h>` in the c file and it works out.  Thank you for your help again! : )

Answer (score 1):

A system call is supposed to be used by an application program to avail a service from kernel. You can implement a system call in your kernel module, but that should be called from an application program. If you just want to expose the statistics of your new scheduler to the userspace for debugging, you can use interfaces like proc, sys, debugfs etc. And that would be much more easier than implementing a system call and writing a userspace application to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try these interfaces later. :)